# Twig - Access array[key +1]

Tags: twig

I have a twig template to which I pass this parameter:

```
mediasInAlbums = array(
    "albumId1" => array(media1, media2, media3...), 
    "albumId2" => array(media1, media2, media3...),
    "albumId3" => array(media1, media2, media3...),
    ...
);
```

Here is a sample of the template:

```
{% for album in albums %}
<div class="pictures_wrapper" id="pictures_wrapper_{{ album.id }}">

      {% for media in attribute(mediasInAlbums, album.id) %}
      <div class="picture_wrapper">
          <div class="picture" id="picture_{{ media.id }}"
              data-src="www/images/medias/{{ media.fileName }}.{{ media.fileExtension }}"
              data-slide-to="{# HELP NEEDED HERE #}">
          </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}

      </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm trying to get the id of `mediasInAlbums[albumId][media(key+1)]`. So for example if `loop.index = 2`, I want to access `mediasInAlbums[albumId][media3]->id`. 
Is anyone able to help me with this? :-)

**FOUND SOLUTION:**

```
{{ attribute(mediasInAlbum, loop.index0 + 1).id }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use expression as key.

Try

```
{{ mediasInAlbums[albumId]["media" ~ (loop.index+1)].id }}
```

So you template will look like

```
{% for album in albums %}
<div class="pictures_wrapper" id="pictures_wrapper_{{ album.id }}">

      {% for media in attribute(mediasInAlbums, album.id) %}
      <div class="picture_wrapper">
          <div class="picture" id="picture_{{ media.id }}"
              data-src="www/images/medias/{{ media.fileName }}.{{ media.fileExtension }}"
              data-slide-to="{{ mediasInAlbums[album.id]["media" ~ (loop.index+1)].id }}">
          </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}

      </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thx for your help. Finally, I managed with this:
{{ attribute(mediasInAlbum, loop.index0 + 1).id }}